# Bash Script Add, Delete users?

Tags: linux, bash

i am currently trying to create a script which presents any particular person with a menu when running this particular bash script. On the menu i have allowed three options (1. Add user, 2. Delete user and 3.Quit). In relation to the add user option once selected there should be 2 options which allow the user to manually input details for a new user or add multiple users via a text file. I have been able to create the menus/options described above although i have been unable to create the script/body of the tasks for the add user manually and many users via txt file aswell as delete user.

Any help with my code would be much appreciated! thanks a lot!

Here is my script as of now :

```
    #!/bin/bash
clear
echo "########## MENU ############\n"
options=("add_user" "delete_user" "exit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
case $opt in
    "add_user")
        clear
    while [ 1 ]
do
  clear
  echo "1. Add user manually"
  echo "2. Add user via TXT file"
  read -p "Enter your choice" ch
  case $ch in 
      1)
        read -p "Enter user name : " useradd
       read -p "Enter user password:" passwd
    echo -e "Successfully added the user"
    ;;
    2)
   if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
  for row in `more $1`
  do
  username=${row%:*}
  password=${row#*:}

 egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null

 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$username exists!"
    exit 1
 else
    pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
    useradd -m -p $pass $username
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a 
user!"    
fi
done
else
    echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
    exit 2
fi    
esac  
done
    ;;
    "delete_user")
        read -p "Enter a User name to delete "UNAME
        passwd
        deluser $UNAME
        echo "User $UNAME has been deleted"         

        ;;
    "exit")
        break
        ;;

    esac
done
```

Comment: Many problems. Few recommendations: 1) for the development/debugging is not a best practice foce the developer be root (add the root check, when the main logic works)  2.) you can use nested `select`s (for the add user), 3.) set PS3 for the nicer select's prompt, 4.) your `clear` clearnig your error messages, so you should either don't use clear or pause you script after the error messages 5) why you using `more` instead of `cat` or (better) an simple redirection to while-read loop? 6) finally, the most important - break your script into bash-functions for better manageability.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I don't entirely understand what you mean as i am what you would call a noob. If you wouldn't mind, would you be able to reply with an improved script. Needing it ASAP. Means alot, thanks.

Comment: Reading a password into a variable in a shell script is bad practice. While automating user addition is a laudable goal, it's generally better from a system admin standpoint to do it manually. All aspects can be automated easily except the password. There is no clever way to take the password and avoid intermediate storage in a manner than can be theoretically compromised. Far better to handle creating the users, setting the home options, default group, additional group membership and then come back and set an appropriate password.

Answer (score 0):

For getting idea how to break an big script into small parts. The next is **far** from an good code, but you can get the idea, how to continue.

```
#!/bin/bash

setps3() {
    PS3="$1 (press enter for choices)>"
}
setmainprompt() {
    setps3 "Main menu"
}
setaddprompt() {
    setps3 "ADD USER menu"
}

pressenter() {
    read -p "Press enter to continue:" _tmp
}

err() {
    echo 1>&2 ${CMDNAME} ERROR: $*
    return 1
}
msg() {
    echo ${CMDNAME} NOTICE: $*
    return 0
}

badchoice() {
    err "Bad choice!";
    return 1
}

do_add_one_user() {
    _name="$1"
    _pass="$2"
    echo "add code here for adding one user: ${_name} ${_pass}"
    pressenter
}

do_manual_add() {
    read -p "Username:" _username
    read -sp "Passowrd:" _password
    echo
    do_add_one_user "${_username}" "${_password}"
}

do_txt_add() {
    read -p "Filename:" _filename
    [[ -z "${_filename}" ]] && return
    echo "add code here for adding users from ${_filename}"
    echo "The code should call do_add_one_user function for every line"
    pressenter
}

do_adduser() {
    setaddprompt
    _arr_add=("Add manually" "Add via TXT" "return to main menu" "exit program")
    select add_action in "${_arr_add[@]}"
    do
        case "$REPLY" in
            1) do_manual_add ;;
            2) do_txt_add ;;
            3) return ;;
            4) exit 0 ;;
            *) badchoice ;;
        esac
        setaddprompt
    done
}

do_deleteuser() {
    echo "enter code for deleting user here"
    pressenter
}

uidcheck() {
    owner=${owner:-$(/usr/bin/id -u)}
    if [ "$owner" != "0" ]; then
        err 'Must be root'
        exit 1
    fi
}

## MAIN PROGRAM

CMDNAME=$(basename $0)
#uidcheck   #uncomment when need

_arr_main=("Add user" "Delete user" "Exit program")
setmainprompt
select main_action in "${_arr_main[@]}"
do
    case "$REPLY" in
        1) do_adduser ;;
        2) do_deleteuser  ;;
        3) exit 0 ;;
        *) badchoice ;;
    esac
    setmainprompt
done
```

Comment: Hey, just one more question. I um unsure of how to write the code for the do_add_one_user method which is the only point i am stuck on. Thanks a lot

Comment: Adding users is system dependent. Isn't possible to write it portable... That is the part, what you should do...